# Redirect URL error in facebook api in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I downloaded facebook api from this link

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

After logged in screen I am getting an pop up screen with message " Cannot Open Page Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid".

Why this error is occurring?

Comment: Its working now. here is the reference link https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/205